# Is there any method for namespacing resolution of module names in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Like it works in C# / Java e.t.c, where you don't have to worry about the location of the file, the compiler will be responsible for correctly resolving the dependencies...

At the moment relative paths are used for JavaScript modules `import something from '../../../../Something'` and that long path can be resolved using configurations in webpack and/or gulp e.t.c, but it is still vulnerable to file location change. So if there is a module being used in many other files moving it is not an option, better to duplicate and use new path for other files and slowly refactor the old ones.

Is there any solution to this? Am i missing something or thinking about in the wrong way? (I tried TypeScript namespaces but they don't act like this, weren't what i expected, and i'm not that into using languages that compile to JS)

Comment: I just got what you are asking. Node has `var name = require("moduleName");`. If you want to use a method from `moduleName`, you just have to do `name.method();`.

Comment: It looks like the OP wants to write `import module`, so that JS knows where this `module` is located without necessity in defining a path.

Comment: yes, what @YeldarKurmangaliyev said. Like it works in compiled languages. I know JS isn't a compiled language, but there might be a tool i don't know about.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the JavaScript language, but with your module loader/resolver. As @ahitt6345 said, just name your modules instead of using paths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript)

Comment: in _C# / Java e.t.c_ it works because path settings inside project file